# Get the stored procedure code from Java

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

Can we get the stored procedure content that is declared inside Oracle SQL from java using JDBC?

Background: I have a stored procedure that has an `insert` in it. When I add the stored procedure for inserting every record to the `executeBatch()`, the performance of the `executeBatch()` is not as expected as it would be when single `insert` statements are added.

Also I don't want to change much in the code and don't want to try other options like using `inserts` inside the code and passing the records as a list to the array. So in this case the most preferable choice is to find a way to extract the code inside the SQL stored procedure.

Comment: "Also I don't want to change much in the code and don't want to try other options like using inserts inside the code and passing the records as a list to the array." Why you don't want to do that? In "good practice", you create a DB procedure to handle DML procedures, called from web-app. Often, you create it for one record, but also (like in your case) mass-insert cases also. If you work with Oracle DB, and have access to it - AVOID putting business logic in web-app, implement it in DB - way more efficient and easier to maintain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can obtain the source code for a procedure from the ALL_SOURCE view:

```
SELECT *
  FROM ALL_SOURCE s
  WHERE s.OWNER = 'WHATEVER' AND
        s.NAME = 'WHATEVER'
  ORDER BY s.LINE;
```

Best of luck.

Comment: Or select text from ... to get only source_code.

Comment: @MT0: changed to reflect the upper-case-ish nature of Oracle names.